# Cutting bevel in mesh surface

Tags: modifiers

In the picture I've selected the edge loop I would like to see "cut out" like a bevel, so like a kind of **groove** in the cube's surface. The Bevel Modifier only seems to work on edges that are at the cube's actual edges. I tried assigning the loop edge to a vertex group, and then select "vertex group" in the bevel modifier, but to no avail. Please advise

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do 3 loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) really close to eachother. Then select the one in the middle (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right Click) and scale it down (<kbd>S</kbd>).

Another option would be to separate the mesh by the selected loop. I don't remember if you can do that, but you can always select half the cube and make it a new object (<kbd>P</kbd>), then join it back again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

Excuse my poor answer but I don't have Blender on this computer to give you some pictures.

Comment: Definitely! I've also done something similar with the Subsurf Modifier, where the solution was to add a loop cut really close to another one.

Comment: Works! But is there also a way to do it using a Modifier? In that way the geometry doesn't get "destructed". You know, where the edge loops is marked as a "bevel edge" or something, and the cutting out is then done automatically (and reversibly) by the Modifier.

Comment: I don't really know, but if you go for my first option you would only be adding some extra vertices. The second option will disconnect your mesh in two pieces. Edit: No, sorry. It's just the way it works, it needs to have a difference in height to make a bevel.

Answer (score 3):

Using the bevel tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) you can create a couple of loop cuts parallel to the edge you want to indent.

Then select the middle loop ring and scale it down:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You only missed to add the bevel modifier to see the groove the OP was talking about. If this is what he wanted, I think your answer is clearer :)